# Angular 11 does not load HTML from Component

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

i have a question.
I have 2 router outlets in my angular app.
First one is in app.component.html and is loaded for regular users and site visitors. The router works fine and all components in it are being perfectly loaded

```
<ng-container *ngIf="!isAdmin">
 <app-header></app-header>
 <router-outlet></router-outlet> 
 <app-footer></app-footer>
</ng-container>
```

Here is the appRoutingModule, which is forRoot

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { CatalogComponent } from './movies/catalog/catalog.component';
import { NotFoundComponent } from './not-found/not-found.component';
import { AuthActivate } from './core/guards/auth.activate';
import { AboutComponent } from './about/about.component';
import { ReqComponent } from './req/req.component';



const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    pathMatch: 'full',
    redirectTo: '/home'
  },
  {
    path: 'home',
    component: HomeComponent,
  },
  {
    path: 'about',
    component: AboutComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'catalog',
    component: CatalogComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthActivate],
    data: {
      authenticationRequired: true,
      authenticationFailureRedirectUrl: '/',
    }
  },
{
  path: 'req',
  component: ReqComponent,
  canActivate: [AuthActivate],
  data: {
    authenticationRequired: true,
    authenticationFailureRedirectUrl: '/',
  }
},

// all others
  {
    path: '**',
    component: NotFoundComponent
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {enableTracing: true})],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

I have a second route outlet for admin users only. If user that logs is admin, the dashboard is being showed. It loads entirerly different css, header and footer.  The outlet has its own routing, which works.

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { AuthActivate } from '../core/guards/auth.activate';
import { UserslistComponent } from './userslist/userslist.component';
const routes: Routes = [

  {
    path: 'admin-home',
    component: UserslistComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthActivate],
    outlet: 'admin',
    data: {
      authenticationRequired: true,
      admin: true,
      authenticationFailureRedirectUrl: '/about',
    }
  },
  {
    path: 'userlist',
    component: UserslistComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthActivate],
    outlet: 'admin',
    data: {
      authenticationRequired: true,
      admin: true,
      authenticationFailureRedirectUrl: '/about',
    }
  },

];


@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AdminRoutingModule { }
```

the outlet in app.component.html

```
<ng-container *ngIf="isAdmin">
 <app-adminheader></app-adminheader>
 <router-outlet name="admin"></router-outlet> 
 <app-adminfooter></app-adminfooter>
</ng-container>
```

So both outlets work fine for different users. Header and footer depending on user permissions are loaded and displayed correctly.

But if i want to render HTML in the page body in between header and footer for admin, for example as the root displays, under 'userlist' load UserListComponent. the html of this userListComponent is not being displayed
I tried with 5 newly created components.

Is there any explanation on this?
Thank you for your time :)

Answer (score 0):

And if checked in DOM, we see that the router-outlet is shown, but it is empty

schreenshot shows empty dom, white space, where the component userslistcomponent should be rendered and on the left side - part of the adminheadercomponent, which displays correctly

[image]

Answer (score 0):

How do you access the "admin" routes?
With that implementation the URL that should show the proper admin component should look like this:

```js
'/home/(admin:admin-home)'
```

are you doing that?

I'm not sure if you get the idea of secondary routes correctly :) - secondary routes (so the ones with `outlet`) are kind of like a child to the main route - I mean that in one time we can use two router-outlets.

In your case there are just two different route trees - one for regular users and one for admin. Therefore you shouldn't use secondary routing, but instead design the architecture like this:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="admin">
  <app-admin-header></app-admin-header>
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  <app-admin-footer></app-admin-footer>
</ng-container> 

<ng-container *ngIf="!admin">
  <app-header></app-header>
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  <app-footer></app-footer>
</ng-container>
```

and the routes config:

```js
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'home',
    component: HomeComponent,
  },
  {
    path: 'admin-home',
    component: AdminHomeComponent,
  },
  ...
]
```

Then you can access regular home by resolving route `/home/` and admin home with `/admin-home/`. These two routes are on the same level - think about them as two separate ways to go :)

Comment: I do reply in a post since its a long comment :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answer

Hi answering your question, i do access admin routes like this

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'home',
    component: HomeComponent,
  },
  {
    path: 'admin-home',
    component: AdminHomeComponent,
    outlet: "admin"
  },
  ...
]
```

. with outlet: "admin" i enter the admin router outlet. I use different modules for different paths. For example, for user i have this routing module

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { AuthActivate } from '../core/guards/auth.activate';
import { LoginComponent } from './login/login.component';
import { ProfileComponent } from './profile/profile.component';
import { RegisterComponent } from './register/register.component';
import { EditProfileComponent } from './edit-profile/edit-profile.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'login',
    component: LoginComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthActivate],
    data: {
      authenticationRequired: false,
      authenticationFailureRedirectUrl: '/',
    }
  },
  {
    path: 'register',
    component: RegisterComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthActivate],
    data: {
      authenticationRequired: false,
      authenticationFailureRedirectUrl: '/',
    }
  },
  {
    path: 'profile',
    component: ProfileComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthActivate],
    data: {
      authenticationRequired: true,
      authenticationFailureRedirectUrl: '/login',
    }
  },
  {
    path: 'edit-profile',
    component: EditProfileComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthActivate],
    data: {
      authenticationRequired: true,
      authenticationFailureRedirectUrl: '/',
    }
  },

];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class UserRoutingModule { }
```

Meaning i do separate the routes specific for the user in this module. This works. I did separate the routes for the admin as well for user and quest and i decided to use another outlet for admins only, this is when i realised html is no longer rendered for the components, represented by this new outlet. the components i render with
user-routing.module.ts
guest-routing.module.ts

work fine, but they get the routes from the main outlet

I will try to use the main outlet for the admin routes as well, as you proposed , will see thanks :)

Comment: sure :) like I said - secondary routing may not be perfect for your case - you have a few independent routes which shouldn't use secondary routing because you don't expect to show many router-outlets on a single page. Secondary routes are usually for displaying two+ views at once, like with a sidebar or something